# using :APP_USER in a query in apex application

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, apex

I have a query in my apex page and I want to see the result of this query in the page:

```
    select locs.LOCATION_DESCRIPTION "LOCATION", rsrv.Room_ID "Room Number", 
    rsrv.WORKPLACE_ID "Desk Number", rsrv.RESERVATION_DATE "Date", rsrv.TIME_FROM 
    "From", rsrv.TIME_TO "To"
       FROM WPB_RESERVATIONS rsrv, WPB_USERNAMES usrs, WPB_LOCATIONS locs
          WHERE upper(usrs.APEX_USERNAME) = upper(:APP_USER)
               AND (upper(rsrv.FIRST_NAME) = upper(usrs.FIRST_NAME) AND upper(rsrv.LAST_NAME) = 
    upper(usrs.LAST_NAME))
               AND rsrv.LOC_ID = locs.LOC_ID
               AND rsrv.RESERVATION_DATE >= SYSDATE-1
```

but it shows nothing. IT seems this part doesnt work:

```
    WHERE upper(usrs.APEX_USERNAME) = upper(:APP_USER)
```

because when I change it to this I can see the results that I want:

```
    WHERE upper(usrs.APEX_USERNAME) = 'MS'
```

I've read all topics about using :APP_USER or v(APP_USER) and tried different solutions, but non of them works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if it works when you hardcode 'MS' and it does not work when you do `UPPER(:APP_USER)` that indicates that those 2 values are not the same. You have not mentioned what the value for the APP_USER is. Best way to check is to open the session state window from the developer toolbar and check what the value for "User" is.

Comment: I have tested the value of APP_USER, I've created a page item with this expression : " select :APP_USER from dual"  and displeyed it, the value is the same as 'MS'
but even when I use this variable or the expression, nothing comes as result.

Comment: Use the ```DUMP``` function to check if there are no garbage characters in the APP_USER. Compare the result to ```SELECT DUMP('MS') FROM dual```

Comment: DUMP('MS') FROM dual  --> Typ=96 Len=2: 77,83
DUMP(:APP_USER) --> Typ=1 Len=2: 77,83

is it the problem?
should I change data type to VARCHAR2 in database?

Comment: @monashiri can you explain what the problem was exactly ? I'm curious

Comment: the :APP_USER data type in the apex apllicatin was 1 which means varchar2, and the APEX_USERNAME datatype(which is a column in a table in my db and I created it myself to store users firs_name and last_name ) was 96 which means char or nchar, I changed the apex_user column datatype in my db to varchar2 and the problem is solved !!

Comment: Ah ok - yes that explains

Comment: @monashiri just wanted to add a last comment: I'd avoid using datatypes like char/nchar unless you have a really good reason. VARCHAR2 should be good for any  type of string values (more info [here](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:72243456808191))

Comment: Extending the suggestion for the DUMP function, if you add a second parameter to it, you can see the character set, which might answer your question. e.g. 
    SELECT DUMP(:APP_USER, 1010) FROM dual;

Answer (score 1):

If you're still working on this, my suggestion would be to temporarily:

1. Hardcode the 'MS' into the WHERE clause (or drop that comparison entirely,
2. Add a dummy column to your query with this as the source

```sql
upper(:APP_USER) AS the_app_user
```

That will let you see the application item value in the report results.